# How to write command in process Builder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am Running shell script using cygwin and java.

```
ProcessBuilder pb =new ProcessBuilder
("sh", "app.sh", "ib2", "12", "11", "AK-RD", "02.20", "D:\\cygwin\\bin\\test\\delta");
```

My script is running when i am hard coding parameters. I want to pass these parameters through text box values.

How to do this.

```
 String cmmd[] = new String[8];
        cmmd[0] ="\"sh\"";
        cmmd[1] ="\"app.sh\"";
        cmmd[2] ="\""+txt_threeltr.getText()+"\"";
        cmmd[3] ="\""+txt_month_c.getText()+"\"";
        cmmd[4] ="\""+txt_year_C.getText()+"\"";
        cmmd[5] ="\""+txt_partNumber.getText()+"\"";
        cmmd[6] ="\""+txt_version.getText()+"\"";
        cmmd[7] ="\""+txt_destinationname.getText()+"\"";
```

**`ProcessBuilder pb =new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.toString(cmmd));`**

Or is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ProcessBuilder` has a varargs string constructor, you can do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmmd);
```

Alternatively, don't construct an array. Create it like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder ("sh", 
                                        "app.sh", 
                                        txt_threeltr.getText(), 
                                        txt_month_c.getText(), 
                                        txt_year_C.getText(), 
                                        txt_partNumber.getText(), 
                                        txt_version.getText(), 
                                        txt_destinationname.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProcessBuilder` has a vargs constructor that you can pass your array to.  Pass the values exactly as input from the text boxes (**no quotes**), and it will take care of any necessary escaping for you.